Unable to Host Flask App as a Application in IIS - Getting 404 error. The requested URL was not found on the server
I followed this article and successfully hosted the flask app as a website.
However, I wanted to host it as an application under the default website, so I can have other apps installed too under Default Web Site for local network testing. This way I can use the server name with the application alias to browse the application.
I tried following this link but that did not help, I am getting a 404 with "The requested URL not found" error.
This is my app.py code.
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import subprocess
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='.')

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')


@app.route('/execute_script', methods=['POST'])
def execute_script():
    foldersf = request.form['foldersf']
    datef = request.form['datef']
    folderss = request.form['folderss']
    dates = request.form['dates']

    # Call the Python script with the provided arguments
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(
            [r'C:\Python\python.exe', 'job.py', foldersf, datef,
             folderss, dates],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

        # Check if the script execution was successful
        if result.returncode == 0:
            output = result.stdout.strip()
            additional_message = "Script executed successfully"
            combined_output = output + '\n' + additional_message
            return combined_output, 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
        else:
            error_message = result.stderr.strip()
            return f'Error executing script: {error_message}', 500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
    except Exception as e:
        return f'Error executing script: {str(e)}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


You followed out-of-date articles. https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
